# Knockout updating the UI when values are same

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a text input control with value binding. For the value property I have an extender.

The whole idea is to achieve the scenario of whenever the value is getting emptied I want to set it back to the old value.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfp5R/18/)

```
ko.extenders.myextender = function (target, precision) {
//create a writeable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
var result = ko.computed({
    read: target, //always return the original observables value
    write: function (newValue) {
        alert(target.peek());
        if (!newValue) {

            //target("");
            target(target.peek());
            target.notifySubscribers(target.peek());
        }
    }
});
return result;
}
function viewModel() {
    this.Value = ko.observable("abcd");
    this.Value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        alert("Do something with the newValue");
    });
    this.Value = this.Value.extend({
        myextender: 0
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

The problem is Whenever I set back the old value it's not reflecting in the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues with your current code:

- You don't set the `target` property when the `newValue` is not empty. So it does not update your underlaying observable when you change something in the input.
- In the empty value case you need to call `notifySubscribers` on your computed and not on the uderlaying observable `target`. Because your computed is bound on the UI so that has to notify the value binding about its value change.

So your fixed computed should look like this:

```
var result = ko.computed({
    read: target, //always return the original observables value
    write: function (newValue) {
        if (!newValue) {
            target(target.peek());
            // notify the subscribers to reset the value in the input 
            result.notifySubscribers(target.peek());
        }
        else{
            // newValue is not empty so set the target
            target(newValue);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29xpJ/).

Comment: Hello sir thanks for the reply, I want to know why the subscription(`Value.subscribe`) written to the value dint get trigger, reason why I ask is, in my actual implementation it's triggering the subscribe.

Comment: Your comment is a little bit unclear. But if you want to `Value.subscribe` triggered when both you change the value and for the empty case then you need to `notifySubscribers` both on `value` and `result`: http://jsfiddle.net/jWB8p/. You should note that `target(target.peek());` does not trigger the `Value.subscribe` because KO has an optimalization: if you set an observable to the same value then it does not trigger the subscriptions.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfp5R/24/), here the subscribe is getting called. I am bit confused with the behaviour

Comment: The order of the `this.Value.subscribe` calling is different. In your original code you have first created the `Value` observable then subsribed on the `Value` observable then you have overriden the `Value` property with your new computed. So you have subscribed on the underlaying `target` observable. In you new fiddle you have created the `Value` observable then you have overriden with the new computed then you have subscribed on the new computed. So in your last fiddle you are subscribed the `result` ko.computed.

Comment: So it does matter when do you call `this.Value.subscribe` before of after the `extend`.